# Elastic search multi index search with different attribute

Tags: elasticsearch

Facing issue while query with multi index queries. I have multiple indices with different attributes. I want a query which return result from all indices and filter result only if one attribute present.

Currently If attribute is not present it does not return the response for that index.

Example:

```
FirstIndex {
    attribute: {
         type: type1
         flag: false
    }
}

SecondIndex{
    attribute: {
         type: type1
   }
}
```

above flag the `attribute:flag` is not there so if search is on `flag=false` it should return both matching as well as `secondIndex`. Something like outer join in dbms.

Answer (score 0):

probably you can give a try with the following query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {
              "exists": {
                "field": "user"
              }
            },
            {
              "missing": {
                "field": "user"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In the field column add the fields required.